# How to Get the "Code39" Barcode Information?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, isbn, code39

I have a "code39" barcode. How can I get the information from that bar code: product name, manufacturer, and everything else?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Find a bar code scanner that reads code 39 encoding--which is just about all of them, and scan  the bar code. That number will normally be a [GTIN - Global Trade Item Number](http://www.gtin.info/). You will have to use that number and query some kind of database or web api to get the rest of the product data.

Comment: Thank you shane, for your reply. I am able to scan the barcode and able to get the barcode number. Could you please suggest me any web api(like any web service) to get the barcode information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043579/getting-product-information-like-name-price-etc-using-barcode-number