# How can i get product information from barcode in android?

Tags: android

Google has shut down the Search API for Shopping so what is the possible way to get product info ( manufacturer name, product number etc.) from barcode in android?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this api](http://www.outpan.com/developers_get_product_data.php) from www.outpan.com

Answer (score 0):

```
try {             

                 json = products(upc);

            return json.getString(params[0]);         
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {             
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block             
                e.printStackTrace();        
            } catch (IOException e) {             
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block             
                e.printStackTrace();         
            } catch (JSONException e) {             
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block            
                e.printStackTrace();         
            }
```

[Once visit this this may helpful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043579/getting-product-information-like-name-price-etc-using-barcode-number)